# How to query Wikidata items using its labels?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

How can I query Wikidata to get all items that have labels contain a word?
I tried this but didn't work; it retrieved nothing.

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel.  
  }
FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(?itemLabel), "keyword"))
}
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: What is `wikibase:label`? Without prefixes it's hard to say what's going wrong.

Comment: PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>

Comment: And where is the `wikibase:language` information in this dataset? Without, the join is obviously empty in the SERVICE part which is executed as a single SPARQL query.. I think it could work if you put the first triple outside of the SERVICE clause.

Comment: Thanks AKSW for your answer. I tried it but got "QUERY TIMEOUT
ERROR: SPARQL-QUERY: queryStr=SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
  }
  ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel.  
   FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(?itemLabel), "palestine"))
}"

Comment: I meant it the other way around. I thought you want to use the labels from the ontology graph `http://wikiba.se/ontology-1.0.owl#` which you specified with the SERVICE clause. And this one does not contain the property `wikibase:language`, therefore you should put this one outside of the SERVICE clause, not the other one. But to be honest, it's not clear what you want to get with your query. Especially, the graph that you specify with `SERVICE wikibase:label` should be what? You use a prefixed URI for the property, but maybe you want just the ontology.

Comment: Where do you run your query? And why can't you simply do this on the Wikidata SPARQL endpoint without using the SERVICE clause?

Comment: I just updated the query to: "SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE
{
  ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel.
  FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(?itemLabel), "keyword"@en)).
}
limit 3 ". It works in most of the cases but returns "Query deadline is expired"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following your question and the useful comments provided, I ended up with this query

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
WHERE { 
  ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel. 
  FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(?itemLabel), "city"@en)). 
} limit 10
```

For which I got those results

```
item          itemLabel
wd:Q515       city
wd:Q7930989   city
wd:Q15253706  city
wd:Q532039    The Eternal City
wd:Q1969820   The Eternal City
wd:Q3986838   The Eternal City
wd:Q7732543   The Eternal City
wd:Q7737016   The Golden City
wd:Q5119      capital city
wd:Q1555      Guatemala City
```

[try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FitemLabel.%20FILTER%28CONTAINS%28LCASE%28%3FitemLabel%29%2C%20%22city%22%40en%29%29.%20%7D%20limit%2010)

Comment: Just an update, this query is terminated with timeout exception in most of the cases (for other labels)

Comment: @fattah.safa I just tried it again and it took less than 2 seconds to complete

Comment: as @fattah.safa said, it raises timeout in _many cases_ for **other** labels. I tried to change "city" by other lowercase strings and some work, but some doesn't: i.e. "washington" or "oslo" work, but for example "curitiba" or "ourense" [ends in timeout](https://w.wiki/5DJi), although these places have English [wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q99151) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ourense) entries.  Any clues?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can search by label, for example:

```
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE{  
  ?item ?label "Something"@en.  
  ?article schema:about ?item .
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>. 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
}
```

see it on [Query page](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20WHERE%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22Something%22%40en.%20%20%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E.%09%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D).

Comment: This answer works in 2022. The accepted answer does not.

Comment: What's up with the implicitly defined `itemLabel` and `itemDescription`. I this a SPARQL feature or some weird extension?

Answer (score 3):

As of today (June 2020), the best way to do this seems to be using these CirrusSearch extensions. The following does a substring search in all English labels and comes back with 10,000 results in <20 seconds. I believe it also searches in aliases and descriptions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?label
WHERE
{
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi
  {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org";
                    wikibase:api "Generator";
                    mwapi:generator "search";
                    mwapi:gsrsearch "inlabel:city"@en;
                    mwapi:gsrlimit "max".
    ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:title.
  }
  ?item rdfs:label ?label. FILTER( LANG(?label)="en" )

  # … at this point, you have matching ?item(s) 
  # and can further restrict or use them
  # as in any other SPARQL query

  # Example: the following restricts the matches
  # to college towns (Q1187811) only

  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q1187811 .
}
```

[Link to this query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%3Fisa%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Amwapi%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aendpoint%20%22www.wikidata.org%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3Aapi%20%22Generator%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Agenerator%20%22search%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Agsrsearch%20%22inlabel%3Acity%22%40en%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Agsrlimit%20%22max%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wikibase%3AapiOutputItem%20mwapi%3Atitle.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%20FILTER%28%20LANG%28%3Flabel%29%3D%22en%22%20%29%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ1187811%20.%0A%0A%7D%20limit%20100)

Comment: Seems much faster, but I don't understand how to extend the query, for instance if the label must contain city and the entity be an instance of a place, not a movie etc. etc.

Comment: @GM I’ve edited the example to show how to further restrict the entities.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, querying with case-insensitivity and truncation is very slow in SPARQL query service. 
I found this project on github: https://github.com/inventaire/entities-search-engine
It sets up an ElasticSearch index which allows fast queries for use-cases like autocompletion.