# Easiest way to query if a name exists in Wikidata?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to create the simplest possible query to check if a name exists in Wikidata. For example, I just to want to see if the common name "Jack Smith" is in Wikidata.

Following the example query in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41094508/4561314), I created the following SPARQL query ([run it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20WHERE%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22Jack%20Smith%22%20.%20%20%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E.%09%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%20LIMIT%2010)):

```sql
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE{  
  ?item ?label "Jack Smith" .  
  ?article schema:about ?item .
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>. 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
} LIMIT 10
```

However, it returns zero results.

On the other hand, if I search for "Jack Smith" through the Wikidata *search webpage*, I get back [1200+ results](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?sort=relevance&search=Jack%20Smith) with a lot of people named "Jack Smith".

The behavior with the SPARQL interface is inconsistent. When I run a SPARQL search for "Abraham Lincoln" ([run it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20WHERE%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22Abraham%20Lincoln%22%20.%20%20%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E.%09%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%20LIMIT%2010)), I correctly get back an entry for the American president by that name.

My specific questions are:

1. Why is my SPARQL query returning zero results for "Jack Smith"?
2. What is the simplest API call to check if a name (e.g. Jack Smith) exists in Wikidata? It could be SPARQL or some other REST API.

Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't you use a specific property like `rdfs:label` to check if a person with such a name exist? And literals tend to have a language tag: `SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE{  
  ?item rdfs:label|foaf:name|skos:altLabel "Jack Smith"@en .  
  ?article schema:about ?item .
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>. 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
} LIMIT 10`

Comment: or if you just want to know if there is such an entry which also has a Wikipedia page: `ASK WHERE{  
  ?item rdfs:label|foaf:name|skos:altLabel "Jack Smith"@en .  
  ?article schema:about ?item .
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>. 
  
}`

Comment: Or just `ASK {  
  ?item rdfs:label|foaf:name|skos:altLabel "Jack Smith"@en .  
 
  
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query returns zero results because there is no Jack Smith about whom there is an article in English and is part of Wikipedia.org.

Every line in the body of a SPARQL query is a way to *restrict* the search as opposed to just a way to add new variables.

Look at this query:

```
SELECT ?person ?dateOfDeath
WHERE {
?person a :Person .
?person :date_of_death ?dateOfDeath .
}
```

This would only return people who *have* a date of death, i.e. who are dead, as well as the date.
If you wanted to return people, and *optionally* their date of death, i.e. if they are still alive, you don't want a date, but you *do* want the person, then use this:

```
SELECT ?person ?dateOfDeath
WHERE {
    ?person a :Person .
   OPTIONAL {?person :date_of_death ?dateOfDeath }
    }
```

In terms of your second question, I'd try something like this:

```
SELECT ?boolean
WHERE{
BIND(EXISTS{?item ?label "Jack Smith"} AS ?boolean)
  }
```

This can of course also be issued as, say, a cURL request:

```
curl https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql -X POST --data 'query=SELECT%20%3Fboolean%0AWHERE%7B%0ABIND%28EXISTS%7B%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22Jack%20Smith%22%7D%20AS%20%3Fboolean%29%0A%20%20%7D'
```